# How to add additional sum column to the DataFrame based on specific column groups?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In such case, I have DataFrame like

```
col1  col2
   a     1
   a     2
   a     3
   b     1
   b     2
```

What I want is first groupby `col1` and then sum `col2` columns of the groups, finally add the `sum` to the DataFrame and get

```
col1  col2  sum
   a     1    6
   a     2    6
   a     3    6
   b     1    3
   b     2    3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1**
[**`transform`**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) returns a result with the same index of the original object.
I use `assign` to return a copy of the dataframe with a new column.
See [**split-apply-combine**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) documentation for more information.

```
df.assign(Sum=df.groupby('col1').col2.transform('sum'))

  col1  col2  Sum
0    a     1    6
1    a     2    6
2    a     3    6
3    b     1    3
4    b     2    3
```

---

**Option 2**
Use [**`join`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) on results of normal `groupby` and `sum`.

```
df.join(df.groupby('col1').col2.sum().rename('Sum'), on='col1')

  col1  col2  Sum
0    a     1    6
1    a     2    6
2    a     3    6
3    b     1    3
4    b     2    3
```

---

**Option 3**
Creative approach with [**`pd.factorize`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.factorize.html) and [**`np.bincount`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html)

```
f, u = df.col1.factorize()
df.assign(Sum=np.bincount(f, df.col2).astype(df.col2.dtype)[f])

  col1  col2  Sum
0    a     1    6
1    a     2    6
2    a     3    6
3    b     1    3
4    b     2    3
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('sum')
print (df)
  col1  col2  sum
0    a     1    6
1    a     2    6
2    a     3    6
3    b     1    3
4    b     2    3
```

Or [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by aggregate `sum`:

```
df['sum'] = df['col1'].map(df.groupby('col1')['col2'].sum())
print (df)
  col1  col2  sum
0    a     1    6
1    a     2    6
2    a     3    6
3    b     1    3
4    b     2    3
```